# .Net Core Api Identity in N-layer application making many to many relationship

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, identity

I'm trying to make an application which includes web and mobile UI. In N-layer application my API layer includes ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole. Thus far all is ok. However, in my entity layer the DepartmentUser class can not have an ApplicationUser property because of hierarchical structure. I don't want to give any reference to my entity layer but i need to connect them each other.
[This is the structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyjFH.jpg)

Also because of this situation I am not able to use Fluent Api to make many to many connection on them.

```
    public class DepartmentTeacher
{
    //teacher

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }
}



    modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentTeacher>()
        .HasKey(d => new { d.DepartmentId, d.UserId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentTeacher>()
        .HasOne(d => d.Department)
        .WithMany(d => d.DepartmentTeachers)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentId);


//can not do many to many for user and department
```

Comment: Can you move the appuset and approle in the data access project and then provide the reference in the identity project

Comment: As i know data access layer only includes data access codes not entities. If I do not care the infrastructre of them I would probably move all my entities in the API layer.

Comment: My bad. I didn't see the entity project at all. I meant move appuser and approle in the entity project and then provide reference in the identity project.

Comment: I actually did it already but it brought another troubles with it. In identity it has its own user and role manager. I can simply use it but I can't have any instance one of them. I mean  UserManager<AppUser> manager = new UserManager<AppUser>(); doesn't work. So in Business and Data access layer I can not create the specific classes for user and role. That's actually where I stuck in the project. If I figure this out, I'm going to write here.